# CloudFront is 301 redirecting all my internal links

Tags: 301-redirect, amazon-cloudfront

I do not know why, but all my internal links are `301` redirects.

It is kind of absurd; each single internal link is being redirected to the same resource but as a relative URI.

Example: `coinsocialmedia.com/coins/bitcoin` => `/coins/bitcoin`

Test with Postman below:

[image]

I am afraid that my `www` subdomain redirection might have something to do with it (see below).

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look closely, you will notice that `/coins/bitcoin` is being redirected to `/coins/bitcoin/` with a trailing slash (the trailing slash is an important distinction between the URLs). This is part of "url normalization" and is something that's common for hosting to do. It's unrelated to your www redirect.

The best way to fix this, in my opinion, is to make sure all your internal links are pointed at the version of the page with the trailing slash, as CloudFront is treating that version as the "canonical" version of the page. That way your users will be taken directly to the right page without needing to go through the redirect to add the slash.

Alternatively, you could play around with the treatment of trailing slashes in CloudFront settings, asking CloudFront to never redirect pages to have a trailing slash. See the AWS article [Customizing the URL Format for Files in CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html) for details. But you'll have to be careful that any relative URLs in your pages aren't broken by this, because without a trailing slash, your page's default `base` will be one directory up from where it would have been otherwise.